# Different String output when converting csv file to tab-delimited text file in excel

Tags: excel, type-conversion, csv

In my *CSV* file, there are many text records without any `"` character at the beginning or at the end of each record. but when I convert *CSV* file to *tab-delimited text* file in **excel**, I got a file that some of its records begin and ends with `"` character.
Also when I open my *CSV* file with another file reader like Notepad++, these characters also exist.
So, please explain why this difference occurs and how can I prevent this? (How can I have same file outputs in both *CSV* and text format after conversion?)

Comment: "Also when I open my CSV file with another file reader like Notepad++, these characters also exist" - another file reader other than what?  Seems like this is nothing to do with Excel, since your original CSV file seems to have quotes when viewed in Notepad++

Comment: Yes. also when I open it by notepad, characters also exist. I think it is a excel bug. when I have a xlsx file consist of ID, Text and Label columns, if I delete ID and Label columns and save file as tab-delimited text, quotes are not exist but if at first I save the file as a csv file and then open it and Save it As tab-delimited Text file, quotes exist. @TimWilliams

Comment: So you're not opening your **CSV** file with Notepad++ - you are opening the tab-delimited version - **that is not a CSV file** so your posted problem description is a little confusing...

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry if the title is not clear. The original CSV file **(before conversion)** has quotes and it is visible if be opened by notepad (any file reader except excel!) but in Excel, the file  is shown without quotes. **after conversion**,  Both in the CSV and text file there is no quotes (It doesn't matter whether it opens with excel or notepad or...).

Comment: What's the source of the CSV file?

Comment: [here](https://gofile.io/?c=Hrf8Fg) is the original file. plz convert it to csv and then to tab-delimited text (after deleting first and last column!).